# Excel Shape Color Not Populating

Tags: excel

I have developed a VBA script that (among other things) changes the color of ovals on an Excel sheet based on input data in another sheet. The ovals are part of pre-made groups of shapes that are copied into the workbook with the script. These groups were made a by someone else long before I started working with them.

Most of the time the color population part of the program works perfectly. However, I have found some instances where the color of certain ovals will not populate. Nothing is going wrong in the code. But, if I delete the shape that won't populate color, and copy and paste one that will into its place, it works. The only conclusion that I can come up with is that there is something different about the properties of the ovals. But I'm at a loss for what that might be.

The color is being updated with this statement.

```
Worksheets(sheetName).Shapes(groupName(i)).GroupItems(shapeName(i)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = color
```

But, like I said, the code isn't the issue. That statement works and the color is is not being lost somewhere in the code.

The picture below is the output from a print statement placed right before the part of the code that inserts the color into the oval. If everything is working correctly I would expect to see exactly what I do see.

[image]

The next two pictures show a sample of the shapes in question. The top two ovals and textboxes are in a group named CONN 1. The bottom two are in a group named CONN 2. When the program runs it references the shapes within the group based on the individual name of the shape (ie. The line in the immediate window above that says "CONN 1,AE,362,RED" means that the textbox in CONN 1 next to the AE label should show "362" and the oval should turn red).

Here's what they look like before the program runs.

[image]

Here's what they look like after the program runs.

[image]

The oval on top next to the AF label should have turned red, but it didn't. The difference between CONN 1 and CONN 2 is that in CONN 2 I deleted the oval AF, copied oval AE into the place that oval AF had occupied and renamed it.

Do you have any idea why this might be happening? Thanks.

UPDATE: I just figured out that if I run the macro, select any oval that is not populating with color, manually go to the fill tool and select Automatic, it fills with the proper color.

Comment: did you look at the properties of one that works versus one that doesn't and compare?

Comment: It's really hard to even begin figuring this out with so little detail. There is no way we could replicate this with the information given.

Comment: please add pictures and examples of your code it wuld help everyone understand what you need help with

Comment: Yes. I can't find anything different. But it is worth noting that Excel 2016 lets you view a very limited list of properties that aren't really that helpful.

Comment: The original post has been edited with some code and pictures.